# Mobile (xamarin) App notifications Azure

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, notifications, azure-notificationhub

Using Azure Notification Hub for registering devices and sending push notifications for the App we are developing (iOS/Android) I have two questions :

1. How can I set the Expire Date of a registration or installation? I think I want to set this expire Date to 30 days after registering the device with Azure in order for housekeeping to take place. Or is there another mechanism for Azure for self-cleaning registrations/installations? setting installation.ExpireTime to a specific date time does not seem to do the trick.
2. Say the requested PNS Handle received from Google Cloud Messaging changes, how do I know exactly what registration/installation to update, given the fact that after deleting the App (and getting a new PNS Handle) I no longer know the "old" PNS Handle because the local storage for this app is empty? The user is not unique since the user can have multiple devices. In other words : How do I uniquely identify the device?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39420197/182371) about Expiry date
2. I haven't tried that myself, but it looks like [there're ways to persist local storage across re-installations](https://alexdisler.com/2015/04/23/persist-data-mobile-device-app-removed-uninstalled-cordova-ionic/). But even if you don't do that, what's going to happen is you would register the same handle twice with different registration IDs and the first will just stay for some time within ANH, but you're still going to be using the second one and the device will keep receiving notifications.

Comment: Thank you Nikita, it is indeed a setting on hub level, not registration level.